# Integration by substitution, $\int_1^a f(x^s) dx = \int_1^{a^s} f(x) \dfrac{1}{sx^{1-1/s}} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, substitution

I am trying to show that, for a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, and any $s>0$, $a>1$, we have that $$ \int_1^a f(x^s) dx = \int_1^{a^s} f(x) \dfrac{1}{sx^{1-1/s}} dx.$$

I am trying to use the following result (integration by substitution theorem): $$\int_c^d f(t) dt = \int_{\phi^{-1}(c)}^{\phi^{-1}(d)}f(\phi(t)) \phi'(t) dt,$$
where $\phi$ is a continuously differentiable bijective function.

My attempt is failing as follows:
Let $\phi(t)=t^{1/s}$. Then $\phi(1)=1$ and $\phi(a^s)=a$. Also, $\phi'(t)=\dfrac{1}{s}t^{1/s-1}.$ At this point, I go awry: $$ \int_1^a f(x^s) dx = \int_1^{a^s} f(\phi(x^s)) \phi'(x^s) dx = \int_1^{a^s}f(x)\dfrac{1}{s}(x^s)^{1/s-1} dx.$$
This is incorrect. I have tried to rectify it by using:
$\phi(x^s)=x$ and so $\phi'(x^s) \times sx^{s-1}=1$.

However, this gives $$\int_1^{a^s} f(x) \dfrac{1}{sx^{s-1}}dx.$$

Both attempts I have made are incorrect. Can someone help me understand how I am going wrong here? I am grateful for your help. Thank you.

Comment: The result you are trying to use is literally just the substitution theorem, and as $u(x)=x^s$ is a bijection on $[1,a]$, then just do your substitution as normally

Comment: Hi Lorago, thank you for your comment. I have used the $u$ substitution you have suggested, which did work. But when I instead tried $\phi(t)=t^{1/s}$, it failed, as described above. How did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the following: In your case $\phi(t) = t^s$. So write:
$$
\int^a_1 f(x^s)~\mathrm{d}x = \int^a_1 f(\phi(t))~\mathrm{d}t = \int^a_1 f(\phi(t)) \frac{\phi'(t)}{\phi'(t)}~\mathrm{d}t = \int^a_1 g(\phi(t))\phi'(t)~\mathrm{d}t
$$
We had set $g(\phi(t)) := \frac{f(\phi(t))}{\phi'(t)}$. This seems a little weird at first, but we will just accept it as of now. NOW use substitution $u = t^s$:
$$
\int^a_1 g(\phi(t))\phi'(t)~\mathrm{d}t = \int^{a^s}_1 g(u)~\mathrm{d}u
$$
The difficulty is to write $\frac{f(\phi(t))}{\phi'(t)}$ in terms of $u$. Take a look:
$$
\frac{f(\phi(t))}{\phi'(t)} = \frac{f(t^s)}{st^{s-1}} = \frac{f(u)}{st^{s-1}}
$$
Since $u=t^s$, we get $t = \sqrt[s]{u}$. So:
$$
\frac{f(u)}{st^{s-1}} = \frac{f(u)}{su^{1-\frac{1}{s}}}
$$
This means:
$$
\int^a_1 f(x^s)~\mathrm{d}x = \int^{a^s}_1 \frac{f(u)}{su^{1-\frac{1}{s}}}~\mathrm{d}u
$$

This way - and only this way - is how substitution works. The delicate part is the reciprocal derivative that usually (also in this case) appears. You have to artificially add it in order to be able to use the formula.

Your choice of $u$ was wrong in the first place. And if you call a variable $u$, you should stick to its name all the way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply Meowdog. It was very helpful. Apologies about the $u$; it was from another attempt. Is it possible to salvage the attempt with $\phi(t)=t^{1/s}$? It seems like with this choice of $\phi$, we obtain $$\int_1^{a^s} f(t) \phi'(t) dt,$$ but I am unsure how this comes about.

Comment: No need to apologize for a mistake, we all make them. And no $\phi(t) = t^{\frac{1}{s}}$ is not possible, because you want to get rid of the $x^s$. And your suggestion is not quite correct. We obtain $\displaystyle \int^{a^s} f(u)\frac{1}{\phi'(t)}~\mathrm{d}u$. AND THEN you have to rewrite $\frac{1}{\phi'(t)}$ in terms of $u$, otherwise the integral makes no sense. In the substitution formula, remember, $\int^a_1 f(\phi(t))\phi'(t)~\mathrm{d}t$ is the case of $\int^a_1 f(x^s)~\mathrm{d}s. You have to bring the derivative into the mix.